# Convert phone numbers with brackets in Google spreasheet

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to convert below Phone numbers patterns into single pattern with open and close brackets for first 3 digits using formula only in Google spreadsheet.

214-7671378
214660-9212
214.412-2034
(972) 223-6473
214 502 7196

To

(214) 767-1378
(214) 660-9212
(214) 412-2034
(972) 223-6473
(214) 502-7196

Comment: Google Spreadsheets

Answer (score 2):

In [google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

```
=text(REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(A1,"@"),"\D+",""),"(###) ###-####")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also add query for this type phone number 2145002761

Comment: @Kumark See edit.  Remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Thank you Scott. Working great and saved my day.